# In the game stick with it how do you get the invisible skin?

Tags: ios, stick-with-it

In the game stick with it how do you get the invisible skin? It seems that the only way to get this skin is by buying it, but all the other ones seem to be able to be gotten by completing a section of impossible mode, but I haven’t completed the full impossible mode yet soI don’t know.

It doesn’t say how to get it. here is the game https://apps.apple.com/app/id1513842419.